# Why is a click event not stopped by stopping mousedown/mouseup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Coulda sworn this wasn't how it used to work, but with jquery my click event is firing even if I return false on both mousedown and mouseup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a **click** event is a mousedown **followed** by a mouseup. Stopping/absorbing the ancestor events don't change the fact that they happened, and having happened is all that is required to trigger the descendent.

Comment: More precisely, it is a mousedown followed by a mouseup **on the same element**.

Comment: Right, because if the mouse moves in between, that would trigger a drag event. :)

Comment: The drag event (and mousemove events) may or may not happen also, but the click will only be dispatched if the mouse up and down are on the same element (it's been that way from the very first GUI in 1984).

Comment: I feel like it shouldn't fire click if the mouse moves between mousedown and mouseup, but your answer still seems to be correct.